# ¿Cómo modificar el archivo neo4j.config en una imagen docker de neo4j?

Tags: docker, neo4j

Quiero cargar nodos desde un csv en neo4j:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///Downloads/template_algorithmes.csv' AS line
MATCH (p:Person {name:'Raf'})
CREATE (al:Algorithm {name: line[1], project:line[2], description:line[3], input:line[4], output:line[5], remark:line[9]}), (p)-[:WORKED_ON]->(al)
```

Pero contesta el terminal:

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/Downloads/template_algorithmes_TEITGEN_raphael.csv
```

Entonces tengo que cambiar el archivo de configuración `neo4j.conf` ubicado en `<NEO4J_HOME>/conf` en mi imagen de neo4j pero no sé dónde está el `neo4j_home`.

Según [esta respuesta](https://community.neo4j.com/t/where-is-neo4j-home/6488/5) desde el desplegable `...` debería haber una opción de Terminal que me permitiera encontrarlo. Pero no puedo encontrar este `...`.

[image]

## Modificar el archivo a mano

### Dentro del contenedor

Puedo ejecutar mi contenedor:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run \
   --detach \
   --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
   --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
   --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
   --volume=$HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf \
   neo4j
ccd3b8da2f838770c850017d131c9ed4d3825cdcf7a3aaebf825a611bd58a315
```

Pero cuando llego al sistemo de archivo no hay nano/vim/gedit ...

```
bash-5.1$ docker exec -t -i zoologie /bin/bash
root@15c0a418743c:/var/lib/neo4j# ls
LICENSE.txt   NOTICE.txt  UPGRADE.txt  certificates  data    labs  licenses  plugins
LICENSES.txt  README.txt  bin          conf      import  lib   logs      run
root@15c0a418743c:/var/lib/neo4j# ls
LICENSE.txt   NOTICE.txt  UPGRADE.txt  certificates  data    labs  licenses  plugins
LICENSES.txt  README.txt  bin          conf      import  lib   logs      run
root@15c0a418743c:/var/lib/neo4j# cd conf/
root@15c0a418743c:/var/lib/neo4j/conf# ls
neo4j.conf
root@15c0a418743c:/var/lib/neo4j/conf# nano neo4j.conf 
bash: nano: command not found
```

Y no puedo descargarlo tampoco hasta que no parece que puedo utilisar `apk`

### Fuera del contenedor

Aunque parece que hay un archivo `neo4j.conf` dentro del contenedor no parece que haya lo mismo en el volumen conf que monté:

```
bash-5.1$ pwd
/home/ac/neo4j/conf
bash-5.1$ ls
bash-5.1$
```

## La cadena del directorio de importación es "No Value"

```
Call dbms.listConfig() YIELD name, value
WHERE name='dbms.directories.import'
RETURN value
```

Devuelve: `"No Value"`

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso neo4j Desktop 1.4.10 y para acceder a eso es en la pantalla inicial
[image: Pantalla inicial de Neo4j Desktop]

Adicionalmente, para usar `import from csv`  el archivo lo tienes que guardar en la carpeta import de la db en la que vas a trabajar

[image: abre la carpeta llamada import, donde se guardan los archivos a importar]

exito

Comment: Haaa, no tengo la misma consola que tú. Creo que no tengo el mismo "Neo4j Kernel" "4.3.6" "community"

Comment: La version de la db no creo que importe tanto, porque tengo las mismas opciones incluso para db con la 4.4, anyway creo que este link podria ayudarte https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-get-location-of-neo4j-imports-folder-of-a-db-programmatically/30135/2